# How do I create a summary view of a list that can be filtered by dates?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a calendar for employees that assigns them to a "work period". Each work period is 12 hours long, and employees are typically assigned to 3 straight days of work periods.

The events on the calendar are created as all day events, lasting for the duration of their consecutive work periods (i.e. Employee A has an event assigned to them from 1-3 Jan, they have worked 3 work periods).

The current list view I have created using a calculated field shows all of of the employee's work periods in individual rows and without the ability to filter by date.

Example:

| Employee | Start Date | End Date | Work Prds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 Jan | 3 Jan | 3 |
| B | 4 Jan | 5 Jan | 2 |
| A | 6 Jan | 8 Jan | 3 |
| C | 9 Jan | 11 Jan | 3 |

I want to create a "summary" list view of this calendar that my manager can quickly see the total number of work periods that an employee is assigned during a month in order to fairly distribute work periods. I want to only see one row of Employee A with the total number of work periods assigned based on a date input from my manager so he can quickly filter between months.

Example:

Start Date Filter: 1 Jan

End Date Filter: 31 Jan

| Employee | Work Prds |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

And to make this difficult, I'm not terribly familiar with Designer, so if there is an out of the box web based solution, that would be amazing.

Sorry for the noob question!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way will be using the list view configuration. Go list settings>view, click on the view you want to edit.

I assume the work prds column to be a number column, then you can simply use the `group by` function to filter your list into groups based on Employee. Then use the `total` function to calculate the sum of a number column.
[image]

A test list works like below

[image]

One thing to mention is that the sub total for each group only get displayed when you expand the group. It will show up when the group is collapsed. It is a bit different from your expectation.